# How do I pass message queue messages between publishers and subscribers on physically separate networks

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging

I am looking for a way to facilitate message passing between permanently offline nodes. 
I have a message queue on a VPN and a message queue on an offline network and I want to pass messages back and forth.

I have a design for this, though before making it I want to see if there is anything in RabbitMQ (or other messaging middleware) that could help facilitate such a transfer.

The requirements are to have publishers and subscribers on both networks. There would be a subscriber on an offline network that subscribes to a queue which is populated from a publisher on the VPN network.
There may also be a publisher on the offline network which publishes messages that I want to have an online subscriber subscribe to.
I looked at the Shovel plugin to try and dump messages between networks, though I did not get very far with that.

I am thinking of writing a program that subscribes to all the queues that need to be transferred between networks, writing a big transfer file or set of chunked files, and then transferring between networks.

The challenge here is bi-directional updates. I am also trying to build a data transfer program that a non-programmer can use, some UI with a button called "Transfer Messages" which is as detailed as the process worker has to get.

This is effectively sneaker-netting messages from a queue across physically separated networks. It is not an ideal situation, though it is what I have to deal with. There is no option of moving the offline database online.

I currently have a home-grown transfer program that transfers database events across networks. It worked in the past but does not scale well.

Thanks for any  help on ideas. I am mostly looking for a sanity check to see whether a message queue is a good tool for this job.

Comment: You said you started investigating the shovel plug-in. From what I've read, it sounds like that's exactly what you need. I would recommend doubling down on that approach.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR does shovel support proxying of messages in both directions, or just one-way?

Comment: @Cocowalla The [shovel documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) seems to indicate it's one way only.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR yeah, that's what I had taken from the docs too - but a couple of Pivotal engineers confirmed yesterday that its bi-directional, working as both publisher and consumer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/MzhRt_L2BFo